# Using Jquery to add and remove classes more efficiently based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Using .NET MVC with a view that has a table with 14 columns. I am allowing the user to open a modal and select/deselect checkboxes to hide and unhide these columns. But code is bulky and feels inefficient. It does however work, I'm just seeking an answer on how to make this thing better.

The way I've done it is I've labeled the TH like this

```
  <th id="col1" class="toggleMe1">
         UW
    </th>
    <th class="toggleMe2">
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client)
     </th>
```

AND SO ON for both the TH and TD

```
<td class="toggleMe1">
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameOf)
</td>
<td class="toggleMe2">
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client)
 </td>
```

Here is the Jquery I use. In order for me to isolate these columns individually, without turning off/on others, I've to isolate them this way. ColorMe class has a display:none; property. That's it.

```
if ($("#col1Off").is(":checked")){
       $('.toggleMe1').addClass("ColorMe");
  } else {
       $('.toggleMe1').removeClass("ColorMe");
  }
  if ($("#col2Off").is(":checked")) {
        $('.toggleMe2').addClass("ColorMe");
  } else {
    $('.toggleMe2').removeClass("ColorMe");
  }
```

I have to do this for all 14 columns. Is there a way I can shorten this down? Some more efficient?

EDIT. CODE SNIPPET.

A modal to hold the checkboxes.. Look in div class="Modal-body" find them. There's only two right now

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="col1Off"  data-chclass="toggleMe1" />
                        <label for="col1">Uw</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="col2Off"  data-chclass="toggleMe2" />
                        <label for="col2">Client</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CODE to open the MODAL and the code to toggle the classes for hide/unhide.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes

    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        var el = $(this).data('chclass');
        $('.' + el).toggleClass("ColorMe");
    });


    // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
    // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Hide or Unhide Columns')
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

Much of it is probably not needed. I was just testing out a modal and copied the example code for testing.

I have to open it twice for the toggle class to work

Comment: you can use the jquery function toggleClass("ColorMe"), it allow you to simplify the code http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: jquery actully has show, hide and toggle functions that you could use, if visibility is all you are concerned with

Comment: Yes. Visibility is all I'm concerned with. However, I have tried the toggle class and I can't seem to see how to isolate them individually like this. It applies to all or none. Any examples you care to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You need to have the input change event inside a `$(document).ready()`, so that it is initialized once the DOM is ready. Currently the change listener is added on the modal's `hide.bs.modal` event. 
See code below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var el = $(this).data('chclass');
    $('.' + el).toggleClass("ColorMe");
  });
})

$('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Hide or Unhide Columns')
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="checkbox" id="col1Off" data-chclass="toggleMe1" />
        <label for="col1">Uw</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="col2Off" data-chclass="toggleMe2" />
        <label for="col2">Client</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Add a data attribute, eg. `data-chclass` to each checkbox containing classes of the `<th>` tags.

Eg: `<input type="checkbox" data-chclass="toggleMe1" />`

Then you can use:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var el = $(this).data('chclass');
    $('.' + el).toggleClass("ColorMe");     
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Two things. First, this works. So, thank you. I have to make each class unique within the th and tds to isolate them, but this greatly makes the Jquery more efficient. TWO: I have a modal that holds these check boxes. I have to open it twice for the Jquery to work. First time I open it and check/uncheck the boxes, it does nothing. The second time it works like it's supposed to. Any idea as to why?

Comment: If you can add a minimal code snippet to your answer showing the issue, it will be easier to help

Comment: I don't know how to add the snippet, so I'll adjust my question and put the code up there for you to see.

Comment: It's posted. Hope that provides more info

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I found my problem. Your edit is probably true as well, but I didn't try it that way I had another issue and once I fixed that, it was solved. I had duplicate Jquery Modal code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189268/discussion-between-anurag-srivastava-and-swapmeet-lou).